# core-scaffold and core-item (with link) and several contents

Tags: polymer

I have read the examples of core-elements/demo.html and core-samplers/index.html and there is an example of Scaffold with some core-items. But the core-items have the same content.

How can I have a lot of core-items with differents contents ?

Do you have a real example ?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by "the core-items have the same content"? The demo seems to work for me.

Comment: of course, https://github.com/Polymer/core-scaffold/blob/master/demo.html in this example, you have two core-items, but they have not contents. excepted the <div class="content" /> which is common to both. In this case, do you have an idea to show two different contents in function of the selected core-item ?